# Show data from internet with jsoup

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

The thing is that I manage to bring a data that I want from the internet but it comes with a tag that I would like to remove. I get the data from here:

```
<a style="display: block;" class="btn-collapse" onclick="collapseChapter('collapsible490362')" role="button">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i> 
  Capítulo 120.00
</a>
```

What interests me from there is the data: **Capítulo 120.00**. The problem is that in my application this looks like this:

[image]

This is how I bring the data:

```
protected ArrayList<TMODatosSeleccion> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("valor");

            tmoDatosSeleccions.clear();
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("div.col-10.text-truncate");
                Elements dataDos = doc.select("div.col-2.col-sm-1.text-right");
                for (Element e1 : data) {
                    for(Element e2 : dataDos){
                        String numeroCap = e1.select("a").html();
                        String urlManga = e2.select("a").attr("href");
                        tmoDatosSeleccions.add(new TMODatosSeleccion(numeroCap, urlManga));
                    }
                }
            }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return tmoDatosSeleccions;
        }
```

But this in my `TextView` looks like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i> Capítulo 120.00
```

And like I said, I just want the: **Cápitulo 120.00** to be seen

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: Try to select the text of ```String numeroCap = e1.select("a").text();``` instead of htmlt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the text, use String numeroCap = e1.select("a").text() instead of `html()`. The `html()` method select everything inside the element.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = "<a style=\"display: block;\" class=\"btn-collapse\" onclick=\"collapseChapter('collapsible490362')\" role=\"button\">        <i class=\"fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw\"></i>         Capítulo 120.00      </a>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    String text = doc.select("a").text();
    System.out.print(text);
}
```